# Size of new box rotated and the rescaled

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rotations

I have a box of height h and width w. I rotate it to r degrees. Now I resize it so that it can original box in it. What will be the size of newly box.

**Original Box:**

[image: Original Box]

Box after rotating some degrees.

[image]

New box after rescaling.

[image]

So my question is what should be the formula to calculate new size (width, height), position relative to old one.

What I have Width "w", height "h", position (x,y) and angle (t).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the old rectangle inscribed in the new one, we have the following picture:

[image]

Let $\theta$ ($0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$) the rotation angle, $w'$ the new width and $h'$ the new height, then we have the following equations:
$$w' = w \cos \theta + h \sin \theta$$
$$h' = w \sin \theta + h \cos \theta$$

The new rectangle is not similar to the old one, except for $h = w$ when both rectangles are in fact squares.

**Edit:**

Considering $O$ (the center of both rectangles) as the origin of the coordinate system, the points $E$, $F$, $G$, and $H$ can be calculated by the following equations:
$$E=\left(\frac{w}{2}-w \cos^2 \theta,-\frac{h}{2}-w \sin \theta \cos \theta \right)$$
$$F=\left(\frac{w}{2}+h \sin \theta \cos \theta,-\frac{h}{2}+h \sin^2 \theta \right)$$
$$G=\left(-\frac{w}{2}+w \cos^2 \theta,\frac{h}{2}+w \sin \theta \cos \theta \right)$$
$$H=\left(-\frac{w}{2}-h \sin \theta \cos \theta,-\frac{h}{2}+h \cos^2 \theta \right)$$

Comment: what about the position of new rectangle? E, F, G and H Points, their position relative to ABCD?

Comment: @FaisalHafeez See my edit.